Springdoc OpenAPI add Classpath Yaml
I have an OpenAPI description defined in its own library.
This library is used as a gradle dependency in my project.
I am using Springdoc v.2.5.0.
My project is a Spring Cloud Gateway.
Currently, I am trying to start Swagger-UI and use the existing Openapi.yml that is inside the resources folder of the library. But in the application.yml I can't specify the yaml file directly.
"classpath:/openapi.yml" for example doesn't work, Swagger-UI can't access it that way.
So I looked into writing a Configuration Bean, as I can easily access the yaml file in Java directly, but can't find any way to pass the file to Springdoc or Swagger-UI.
Does anyone know how to do it?

You can just create a bean to read the yaml file and convert it to an openApi obj.
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() throws IOException {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("../../example.yaml");
        String openApiYaml = StreamUtils.copyToString(resource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        OpenAPI openAPI = Yaml.mapper().readValue(openApiYaml, OpenAPI.class);
        return openAPI;
    }
}

also you need these properties in order for spring doc to be enabled
springdoc.api-docs.path=/v3/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html

